# Calculating area of triangles formed by delaunay triangulation using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

After applying delaunay triangulation 160 triangles were formed.

How can I calculate the area of each triangle using Matlab?

Comment: Are you using any GIS software? (if so, please update the question) Area calculation of triangles is a trivial task, even without it (1/2 base*height).

Comment: By looking at the tags Matlab is the preferred tool and it can fore sure handle the (1/2 base*height) formula.

Answer (score 2):

There may well be a better way to do this for the whole triangulation, but here's a way to do it in Matlab for one triangle, which could be repeated. It uses [Heron's forumula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) for the area of a triangle.

`trMesh` is assumed to be the triangulation object.

```
vertices = trMesh.ConnectivityList(ElementNo,:);
vX = trMesh.Points(vertices, 1);
vY = trMesh.Points(vertices, 2);
vZ = trMesh.Points(vertices, 3);
clear vertices;

% we need to add an extra row to vX and vY, to close the triangle. 
vX(end+1) = vX(1);
vY(end+1) = vY(1);

%first, find the length of each side of the triangle, by pythagoras
sl = sqrt(diff(vX).^2 + diff(vY).^2);  %this will give a 3x1 matrix of lengths.
% find half of the perimeter
sp = sum(sl) / 2;
%Heron's formula for area of a triangle
TriangleArea = sqrt( sp * (sp - sl(1)) * (sp - sl(2)) * (sp - sl(3)));
```

Comment: Your code ought to work just fine (+1). There indeed is a better way: it is computationally simpler, faster, and more accurate (because it avoids the square roots).  The area is half the absolute value of the 2D cross-product of two of the triangle's sides, as shown in eq (10) at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html. That computation involves just four subtractions, two multiplications, an addition, forgetting the sign of the result, and dividing by two.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it in ArcGIS 10:

If the features are already single part meaning each triangle has its own record/row in the attribute table you can simply add a new numerical field (type may depend on your specific needs) to the attribute table and use the calculate geometry tool to get the area for each triangle.

If the features are multipart you can use the multipart to single part tool in the data management toolbox or the Explode tool on the advanced editing toolbar to create single part features, then follow the same steps as above to get the area.

Edit: This answer was to the OP which didn't specify the software they planned to use. The question was later updated to refer to Matlab.